# How to Remove Automatic Selection on Text Field when I Start to run my Java Program

Tags: java, swing

Good Day! Why whenever I start my Java Program, the JtextField is always selected even I am not selecting it. Is there any way I can remove it?

Kindly see the picture. Thanks!

[The encircled JTextField is what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1B1M.png)

Comment: What do you want to select instead?

Comment: Nothing, I want to start the program without any selection until the user does

Comment: Doesn't really make sense. Usually when a form is displayed that requires user input focus starts on the first field and the user enters the data and then tabs to the next field. What is the point of not having focus on the first field? If the user likes it there great they just start typing. If they don't like it then the tab/click to the new field. Why force them to ALWAYS tab/click on the new field? Remember when designed a GUI you need to consider users the prefer the keyboard over the mouse. Don't force people to click using the mouse just because you always use a mouse!

Answer (score 0):

Note, what you refer to by "selected" is called "focus" in Swing. That said, there's no such thing as "no component has the focus".

The best thing you can do is give the focus to a non-input element, like the "Information" title field.

Assuming that is a `JLabel`, you'd do something like

```
JLabel informationHeaderLabel = new JLabel("Information");
// ... layout etc
informationLabel.requestFocusInWindow();
```

There's a [tutorial on the Swing focus subsystem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html).